# "Popup is a control part" - what is a 'control part' in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I'm trying to style a ComboBox in Silverlight using Expression Blend.

The ComboBox template contains four items:

- `ContentPresenterBorder`
- `DisabledVisualElement`
- `FocusVisualElement`
- `Popup`

Both `ContentPresenterBorder` and `Popup` contain child elements, and also have a small icon that looks like a jigsaw puzzle piece with a green tick. On mouse-over this icon, I get the tooltip:

> Popup is a control part.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blog.blueboxes.co.uk/2009/02/08/the-use-of-part_-in-control-templates/) explains parts, but effectively it's an element with a predefined type and name. Let's say I want to make a new control called `FancyControl`. Inside my control I want two sliders and for whatever reason, the best way for me to make my control is to have direct access to the `Slider` objects that are created for my control in my code-behind.

I could give them any old name (i.e. "left" and "right"), then find the instances inside `FancyControl.OnApplyTemplate` using `GetTemplatedChild`. The problem with using arbitrary names, is if someone else wants to restyle my control they do not know that the `Sliders` **need** to have the names "left" and "right" for my control to work.

Microsoft used the convention of giving these elements names prefixed with `PART_`. So now when someone restyles my control, they will immediately know that the `Slider` must have the same name (i.e. "PART_Left" and "PART_Right") or else they may lose functionality.

The [TemplatePartAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) can be used to indicate the valid part names and their associated type. This can be used by designers, such as Blend, to properly detect named parts.

It is also worth mentioning that controls should be designed in such a way that if a named part is missing, then it should continue to work with less functionality (i.e. it should not throw exceptions).

Comment: Fantastic answer - this also explains why I see so many controls prefixed with `PART_`.

Comment: Having said that, it seems that for whatever reason the 'parts' inside a ComboBox need to be named `Popup` and `DropDownToggle` in order for the ComboBox to work properly.

Comment: Yes, because in the ComboBox class it uses GetTemplateChild(string controlname) to get these controls. ;)

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - You're right. Looks like Silverlight may not have followed the "PART_" convention, at least not always. If you look at ComboBox in reflector, you can see the TemplatePartAttribute definitions are: `[TemplatePart(Name="ContentPresenterBorder", Type=typeof(FrameworkElement)), TemplatePart(Name="ContentPresenter", Type=typeof(ContentPresenter)), TemplatePart(Name="Popup", Type=typeof(Popup)), TemplatePart(Name="DropDownToggle", Type=typeof(ToggleButton)), TemplatePart(Name="ScrollViewer", Type=typeof(ScrollViewer))]`

Comment: It is fair to say that the easiest way to find the name of the control parts is using Expression?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Personally, I'd use Reflector, but I don't use Blend much. Ultimately, Blend is just looking for the TemplatePartAttribute on the control.